# Mostrar y eliminar filas en la misma función de javascript y la vista en HTML

Tags: javascript, html

```js
< script >
  document.getElementById("agregar-fila").addEventListener("click", function() {
    var table = document.getElementById("tabla");
    var row = table.insertRow(-1);
    var col1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var col2 = row.insertCell(1);
    var col3 = row.insertCell(2);
    var col4 = row.insertCell(3);
    col1.innerHTML = "<input type='text' name='columna1[]' />";
    col2.innerHTML = "<input type='text' name='columna2[]' />";
    col3.innerHTML = "<input type='text' name='columna3[]' />";
    col4.innerHTML = "<button type='button' id='eliminar-fila'>Eliminar fila</button>";
  });

var eliminarFila = function() {
  var fila = this.parentNode.parentNode;
  fila.parentNode.removeChild(fila);
}

var botonesEliminar = document.getElementById("eliminar-fila");
for (var i = 0; i < botonesEliminar.length; i++) {
  botonesEliminar[i].addEventListener("click", eliminarFila);
} <
/script>

<
/html>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <table id="tabla">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Columna 1</th>
        <th>Columna 2</th>
        <th>Columna 3</th>
        <th>Acciones</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="columna1[]" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="columna2[]" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="columna3[]" /></td>
        <td><button type="button" id="eliminar-fila">Eliminar fila</button></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <button type="button" id="agregar-fila">Agregar fila</button>

</body>
```

Estoy desarrollando un ERP y me pidieron que en se realice esta operación, al darle en el botón agregar fila se añade una y al eliminar se quita una aleatoria, acá el código de ejemplo, no se en donde puede estar el error ya que este código me lo entrego un IA y aun así no funciona, principalmente en el ciclo for pareciera ser que no entra, agradecería cualquier ayuda.

Comment: hola @JorgeMendezVelastin. Si la respuesta que te han dado, deberías de marcar cono aceptada para que pueda servir a otro. Puedes hacerlo marcando la "√" que hay a la izquierda debajo de las flechitas. Tambien puedes [hacer un recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y aprender sobre el sitio si tienes que venir con más preguntas. En las guias que hay en [el centro de ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help) podras encontrar información para sacar el máximo partido a este sitio. Haciendo buenas preguntas, tendras opciones de obtener respuestas rápidamente. Suerte

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para agregar puedes crear un `Template` de la fila, y a partir de él clonarlo y copiar su contenido en el `tbody`

Para remover, puedes pasar el mismo boton como argumento y preguntar por el padre de su padre (primer padre es el `td` y el segundo es el `tr`) luego simplemente aplicas la función `remove`

```js
function agregarFila(){
  let template = document.getElementById("templateFila");
  let body = document.getElementById("tablaBody");
  body.appendChild(template.content.cloneNode(true));
}
function remove(btn){
  btn.parentNode.parentNode.remove();
}
```

```html
<table id="tabla">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Columna 1</th>
      <th>Columna 2</th>
      <th>Columna 3</th>
      <th>Acciones</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="tablaBody">
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" name="columna1[]" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="columna2[]" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="columna3[]" /></td>
      <td><button type="button" onclick="remove(this)">Eliminar fila</button></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<button type="button" onclick="agregarFila()">Agregar fila</button>
  
<template id="templateFila">
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" name="columna1[]" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="columna2[]" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="columna3[]" /></td>
      <td><button type="button" onclick="remove(this)">Eliminar fila</button></td>
    </tr>
</template>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, eso me solucionó el problema